# SQL Server agent job execution problems - ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection, jobs

I have a problem while trying to deploy a ssis package from a job. I have created the ssidb folder of the package, and I have not problems to execute it successfully. But when I use a job, by choosing the package from the ssisdb folder, I always get the same error message:

> Failed to acquire connection "database". Connection may not be
>   configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.

The ProtectionLevel of the project and the package is "DontSaveSensitive", but apart of this I do not know what else can I do.

I would appreciate any advice you could give me.

Using SQL Server 2014.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried a proxy account for the job?

Answer (score 0):

It sound's like you have almost worked this out yourself :-) The connection string will most likely not be valid because, when you deployed the package, the password would not have been carried across.
Easiest option if running via SSDB:

1. **On the deployed server** right click on the package.
2. Click configure
3. Amend your connection manager accordingly.

Easiest option if running via SQL Agent Job:

1. Right click job and select properties
2. Click Steps
3. Edit your step.
4. Click on configuration tab.
5. click on connection managers tab.
6. Amend accordingly.

There are, of course, other ways - have a look up Environments.

FWIW We store all our packages with sensitive data secured by a password.